# How can i split and fill value from csv data?

Tags: perl, csv, parsing

How can i Split Value by Newline (\n) in some column, extract to new row and fill other column

My Example CSV Data (data.csv)

```
No,Email,IP,Service,Comment
1,test@email.com,192.168.10.109,FTP
HTTP
HTTPS,,
2,webmaster@email.com,192.168.10.111,SFTP
SNMP,,
3,admin@email.com,192.168.10.112,HTTP,,
```

In Service column has multiple value, separate by new line.

I want to extract it and fill with other value in some row look like this.

```
1,test@email.com,192.168.10.110,FTP,,
1,test@email.com,192.168.10.110,HTTP,,
1,test@email.com,192.168.10.110,HTTPS,,
2,webmaster@email.com,192.168.10.111,SFTP,,
2,webmaster@email.com,192.168.10.111,SNMP,,
3,admin@email.com,192.168.10.112,HTTP,,
```

I try to parsing with Text::CSV, I can only split multiple ip and service But i Don't known to fill other value as above example.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Text::CSV;
my $file = "data.csv";
my @csv_value;
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Could not open $file: $!";
my $csv = Text::CSV->new;
my $sum = 0;
open(my $data, '<:encoding(utf8)', $file) or die "Could not open '$file' $!\n";
while (my $fields = $csv->getline( $data )) {
    push @csv_value, $fields;
}
close $data;
```

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: Are you asking how to access the other fields? They'd be stored in `@csv_value`, ie `$csv_value[1]` for the email

Comment: perl -ne 'if (!/^\d/){print "$line$_";} else {print $_;} /(.*,).*/; $line=$1;' file1

Comment: It's worked, Thanks @EssexBoy , but please explain how it works and if want to write full script, how can i do?

Comment: Your input CSV is broken, e.g. the first row should be (showing the embedded new lines) `1,test@email.com,192.168.10.109,"FTP\nHTTP\nHTTPS",,`. [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) will parse such a file, but you'll need to add the `binary => 1` option to the constructor, as your CSV contains non-ASCII characters.

Comment: @tcc I've added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input CSV is broken. I would suggest to fix the generator.

With correctly formatted input CSV you will have to enable `binary` option in [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) as your data contains non-ASCII characters.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV;

# input has non-ASCII characters
my $csv_in  = Text::CSV->new({ binary => 1 });
my $csv_out = Text::CSV->new();
$csv_out->eol("\n");

while (my $row = $csv_in->getline(\*STDIN)) {
    for my $protocol (split("\n", $row->[3])) {
        $row->[3] = $protocol;
        $csv_out->print(\*STDOUT, $row);
    }
}

exit 0;
```

Test with fixed input data:

```
$ cat dummy.csv
No,Email,IP,Service,Comment
1,test@email.com,192.168.10.109,"FTP
HTTP
HTTPS",,
2,webmaster@email.com,192.168.10.111,"SFTP
SNMP",,
3,admin@email.com,192.168.10.112,HTTP,,

$ perl dummy.pl <dummy.csv 
No,Email,IP,Service,Comment
1,test@email.com,192.168.10.109,FTP,,
1,test@email.com,192.168.10.109,HTTP,,
1,test@email.com,192.168.10.109,HTTPS,,
2,webmaster@email.com,192.168.10.111,SFTP,,
2,webmaster@email.com,192.168.10.111,SNMP,,
3,admin@email.com,192.168.10.112,HTTP,,
```

Answer (score 2):

To expand on my comment

```
perl -ne 'if (!/^\d/){print "$line$_";} else {print $_;} /(.*,).*/; $line=$1;' file1
```

Use the [perl command line options](https://www.perl.com/pub/2004/08/09/commandline.html/)

```
e = inline command
n = implicit loop, i.e. for every line in the file do the script
```

Each line of the file is now in the $_ default variable

```
if (!/^\d/){print "$line$_";} - if the line does not start with a digit print the $line (more later) variable, followed by default variable which is the line from the file

else {print $_;} - else just print the line
```

Now after we've done this if the line matches anything followed by a comma followed by anything, catch it with the regex bracket so it's put in $1. So for the first line $1 will be '1,test@email.com,192.168.10.109,'

```
/(.*,).*/; $line=$1;
```

Because we do this after the first line has been printed $line will always be the previous full line.